# Compare xml of two tables [PENTAHO]

Tags: bigdata, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Do you have any idea how to do something like this in pentaho?
I have two tables. First table it is source table in mssql and second it is target table in db2.
In first table I have column with type xml. We supply second table this data second table. In second also I have column XML. I would like to compare in pentaho whether the xml value in the second table corresponds to what is in the first table.

Comment: To found matching rows, you can use MargeJoin with field xml. It will easy to give you a solution if you tell me what you want if xml values match and what you want if value not match.

Comment: I would like it to do nothing for matching xml, and for non-matching ones, it would write the ID of the record to the file in order to know which record is the difference. I'm just wondering if it will be efficient, assuming that the table has 1000 records for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of "Multiway merge join" & "Switch/Case" step to get the non-matching id from source data. I have prepare a **[SOLUTION](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SrqvJQZ6TRyZb8Wj_f-pN5jz9wGovbQP?usp=sharing)** for you. You can get help from here.

Here

1. Get both table input from MSSQL & DB2
2. Merge both the table data with condition source.XML=destination.xml with **FULL JOIN**
3. Get the source IDs only when IDs are not available in destination table using SWITCH/CASE
4. Select the IDs and write into the text file

[image]